# Creating several graphs using 'for' loop

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, networkx

I have a dataset that looks like

```
Node  Target Group
A       B      1
A       C      1
B       D      2
F       E      3
F       A      3
G       M      3
```

I would like to create a graph for each distinct value in Group. There are 5 groups in total.

```
file_num = 1
for item <=5: # this is wrong
    item.plot(title='Iteration n.'+item)
    plt.savefig(f'{file}_{file_num}.png')
    file_num += 1

    G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='Node', target='Target')

    cytoscapeobj = ipycytoscape.CytoscapeWidget()
    cytoscapeobj.graph.add_graph_from_networkx(G)
    cytoscapeobj
```

This code, however, does not generate individual graphs (G and the objet from Cytoscape), meaning that something does not work within the loop (at least).
Any help would be extremely useful.

Comment: What is `item`? The line `item.plot` suggests that it is a DataFrame but then `item <= 5` in the for loop doesn't make sense

Comment: yeah, It should be a dummy value which runs up to the maximum number of Group in my dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call the DataFrame `df`. Then you iterate over the unique values in the `Group` column, subset df by this Group value, and save a new figure each iteration of the loop.

```
file_num = 1
for group_val in df.Group.unique():
    df_group = item[item['group'] == group_val]
    df_group.plot(title='Iteration n.'+item)
    plt.savefig(f'{file}_{file_num}.png')
    file_num += 1

    G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df_group, source='Node', target='Target')

    cytoscapeobj = ipycytoscape.CytoscapeWidget()
    cytoscapeobj.graph.add_graph_from_networkx(G)
    cytoscapeobj
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Derek. Unfortunately I cannot see any graph, even after replacing item with my df

Comment: When you say you cannot see any graph, do you mean that the `.png` files are blank, or that the line `cytoscapeobj` doesn't display anything in the cell (I am assuming you are using a Jupyter notebook or something similar)

Comment: cytoscapeobj does not display anything. However, it prints correctly df_group.  I was also thinking of something like this (it does not matter if I do not have a png file): `G = [nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df_group, source='Node', target='Target', ) for _ in df.Group.unique()]

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=3)

fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.4, wspace=0.4)
ax = axes.flatten()

for i in df.Group.unique():`, but it does not display correctly the Cytoscape objects

Answer (score 0):

You should use display() function on `cytoscapeobj`:

```py
for group_val in df.Group.unique():
<...>
    display(cytoscapeobj)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).